# I have hourly data of a metric for 15 days, Can i predict the outcome values for same metric for the next 15 days?

Tags: time-series, linear-regression, model-selection

I have tried a linear regression model for the same data, Since the regression line is continuous i'm not sure if it works to predict the outcome values for next 15 days, or for a given period of time!

Are there any models to be considered?

Comment: What do you want to predict exactly? This sounds to me like a [survival analysis problem](https://towardsdatascience.com/survival-analysis-part-a-70213df21c2e), but can't confirm with no data.

Answer (score -1):

If its a timer series data, then according to me you should go for **RNN based model, typically LSTM.**

Also you are looking an output for next "n" days, in this case you have to develop **"Multi-Step LSTM Models".**

> Please refer a very good link on [TimeSeries problems](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/)
>
> Also you can refer TensoFlow code of very basic timeseries problem on
>   [github](https://github.com/vipinbansal1/multipleparalleltimeseries).

**Note: Please modify code for Multi Step problem.**

Comment: A neural network with fifteen observations?